# Back up MacPorts files

Tags: macos, macports

I am planning to migrate from MacPorts to homebrew. Where are all the MacPorts files located (mostly what it installs) so I can back them up? (I do have a regular backup, of course)

Comment: If you can change your vote, give @Chris Johnson the nod. I'd bet my quick-and-dirty answer of "/opt" is probably true for the majority of MacPorts installations out there, but it's true that there are some packages you can install via MacPorts that can put things outside of /opt, as Chris documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast portion of a MacPorts installation is usually<sup>1</sup> under `/opt/local/`, but there are some extra locations that often hold a few other files. See the [Uninstall section](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) of the [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/introduction.html).

Here are the highlights:

- `/Applications/MacPorts/`
  I usually end up with some GUI applications that come with Python in here.
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*`
  Servers ports may drop a file here (e.g. `org.macports.OpenSSH.plist`).
- `/Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg`
  You will have one of these if you used the binary installer (most people probably do).
- `~/.macports`
  Might contain some history or settings for the `port` command.

---

<sup>1</sup>
If you [installed from source or SVN](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html#installing.macports.source), then your installation might be using a directory other than `/opt/local/`.

Answer (score 4):

They're all under `/opt`.